# mounting and unmounting UDF .iso images as a regular user

Tags: mount, iso, fuse, unmounting

I found out about `fuseiso` a while ago but I need to mount UDF images, and it seems like `fuseiso` doesn't support it after failed attempts on my part to mount a UDF image with it. I need to be able to do this as a regular user for arbitrary images and I have to be able to unmount them as well, preferably with the mount-points scoped within a particular user directory (assuming that's not a problem, e.g. `/home/user/mounted/*`), so directly using `mount` doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I'm on Ubuntu and while investigating this I found out about `pmount` but it seems like it doesn't fit my needs because 1) I'm trying to mount an `.iso` file and not a `/dev` block device 2) I wouldn't be able to mount it at a user location (so I could then unmount it as a user, such as by using `fusermount -u` if it were a fuse fs).

```
POLICY
   The mount will succeed if all of the following conditions are met:

   · device is a block device in /dev/

   · device is not in /etc/fstab (if it is, pmount executes  mount device as the  calling  user  to  handle  this
     transparently). See below for more details.

   · device is not already mounted according to /etc/mtab and /proc/mounts

   · if the mount point already exists, there is no device already mounted at it and the directory is empty

   · device  is  removable  (USB,  FireWire, or MMC device, or /sys/block/drive/removable is 1) or whitelisted in
     /etc/pmount.allow.

   · device is not locked
```

What are *any* options I have? In the worst and most discouraged case I imagine as a final resort I would be able to write a custom setuid script to accomplish this? I'm hoping I don't have to risk that though.

Comment: I have no problem mounting ISOs with "Disk Image Mounter" here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What's that? Based on the quotes it seems like it might be a GUI app? I'm trying to do this from the command line, so that I can script it. I guess it would be worth investigating how that GUI app accomplishes it, presumably using some kind of setuid helper.

Comment: grep for that string finds `/usr/bin/gnome-disk-image-mounter`, and unmounting it works as a user.

Comment: Also, I'm specifically referring to UDF ISOs. Regular ISOs mount just fine with `fuseiso`. Thanks! I'll take a look at that, although I'm on a headless server without gnome installed, but I may learn something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `udisksctl loop-setup -f /full/path/to/iso` for that from the udisks2 package.

```
udisksctl loop-setup -f /media/myname/dvd/avatar/buch-1/AVATAR_BK1_VOL1_EUR.iso
    Mapped file /media/myname/dvd/avatar/buch-1/AVATAR_BK1_VOL1_EUR.iso as /dev/loop1.
```

It mounts the iso in /media/$USER/.

If not, you also need to type `udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop1`

```
$ mount | grep udf
/media/myname/dvd/avatar/buch-1/AVATAR_BK1_VOL1_EUR.iso on /media/myname/AVATAR_BK1_VOL1_EUR type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Umount with `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/loop1` if the iso was mapped on /dev/loop1.

Should work without gui too.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I also had to explicitly mount the loop device `/dev/loop0` with `udisksctl mount`, I wonder if perhaps for some people (seemingly those with DEs installed?) it also automatically mounts it just by calling `udisksctl loop-setup`, I wonder if that's some udev rules or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In situations where you do not have the rights to mount, it is possible to use `7zip` to extract UDF ISO files.

While it is not exactly the same as mounting, it might turn out to be sufficient. And if needed, you can even apply modifications and use `genisoimage` to re-create the UDF ISO including your modifications.